# Undecidability of Diophantine equations with disjoint variables?

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations, decidability

Consider a special case of the Hilbert's 10th problem:

$f(\vec{x})=g(\vec{y})$, where $\vec{x}$ and $\vec{y}$ are **disjoint** ( i.e, the LHS and RHS do not have any common variables), moreover, $f$ and $g$ are polynomials with **positive** coefficients.

The question is, with the restrictions, whether the undecidability still holds?

For example, the Pell equation $x^2=3y^2+1$ falls into this class and is difficult to solve. I am wondering whether we can obtain undecidability outright.

[**Important note**: the Hilbert 10th question has two versions, ie., whether there is a solution in natural numbers, or in integers. In general, they are equivalent, but in this particular case, they are not. The answer below shows that checking whether there is a solution in integers is undecidable, but it is still open for the case that the solution must be natural numbers.]

Comment: The Pell equation is not difficult to solve. It is necessary to decompose the coefficient in the continued fraction. Many equations can be solved.

Comment: This problem is at least NP-hard, because the set $\{(a,b,c)\in \mathbb{N}^3|\exists x,y\in \mathbb{N}: ax^2+by=c\}$ is NP-complete.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is undecidable.

The only integral point on $x^3+x=y^2$ is $(0,0)$.

Let $F(\vec{y})=0$ be undecidable diophantine equation with
positive coefficients and not depending on $x$.

Take $f(x)=x^3+x$ and $g(\vec{y})=F^2$ leading to $x^3+x=F^2(\vec{y})$.

To get $F$ from $F'$ with negative coefficients use sum of squares
replacing each negative coefficient $c_i$ with variable $v_i$ and
add the square $(v_i + c_i)^2$.

Even simpler, the integral solutions of $x^2=1+d^2 y^2$ are $(\pm 1,0)$.

Comment: Thanks. I am not clear about the part "get F from F'". For instance, from -2x^3y, what do you obtain?

Comment: Moreover, this answer is nice, but what I meant to ask is whether $f(\vec{x})=g(\vec{y})$ has a solution in **natural numbers** (my apology!) In this case, is the problem still undecidable?

Comment: @Liam_math from $-2x^3y$ I get $(v_1+2)^2+(v_1x^3 y)^2$. For naturals probably every variable should be replaced by sum of 4 squares.

Comment: For the requirement that each variable is in natural numbers, the reduction probably does not work, because $f(\vec{x})=0$ cannot have a solution in natural numbers if all coefficients of $f$ are positive. Again, please correct me.

Comment: @Liam_math for $-2x+4$ the reduction is $(v+2)^2+(vx+4)^2=0$ which forces $v= -2$.

Comment: many thanks. I figured out myself so deleted the comment. Thanks anyway. But I am still puzzled by this natural number restriction. I do not see how the sum of 4 squares works.

Comment: @Liam_math I am not sure about the restriction to naturals. Maybe sum of 4 squares is just one step.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59633/discussion-between-liam-math-and-joro).

Comment: @joro: What do you mean by "$F(\vec{y})=0$ be undecidable"? The undecidability of the Hilbert 10th problem means there is no Turing machine that decides correctly for every two polynomials $f$ and $g$ with positive coefficients whether $f=g$ has a solution in natural numbers or not.

Comment: @ErfanKhaniki, joro means that deciding whether $F(\vec{y})=0$ has a solution. Your statement of the Hilbert 10th problem is clearly correct. The question here is whether the undecidability stands when $f$ and $g$ have disjoint sets of variables.